# Customizing single entry templates in ExpressionEngine (1.6.x)

Tags: content-management-system, expressionengine

This is either very annoying or very embarrassing. I've set up most of my blog, but I can't figure out where or how the heck I set up single entry templates as opposed to the section/weblog containing them. I just can't find information on how to do it for the life of me.

This is especially important, because I want to define the canonical link for all entries, since ExpressionEngine links to entries in all kinds of ways.

So, the case is that I have a Blog section/weblog with an index working as the front page for `mydomain.com`. This lists all my entries as you would imagine a regular blog to do. The problem arises when I need to customize the code for the single entries' links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a template set up already which is showing a multitude of entries and you want a single entry page for each entry then what you need to do is this :

```
{exp:channel:entries
channel="default_site"
sort="asc"
disable="member_data|pagination|categories"}

<a href="{url_title_path="template_group/template_name"}" title="{title}">{title}</a>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Then in the template shown above by template_group/template_name (please change those to whatever your template group and template names actually are ;-) ) you will place this code :

```
{exp:channel:entries
channel="default_site"
limit="1"
dynamic="yes"
sort="asc"
disable="member_data|pagination|categories"}

{title}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This will then show you just the one entry as you will have used the {url_title_path="template_group/template_name"} in the first channel entries tag above which would basically create a URI something like this :

http://www.example.com/template_group/template_name/url_title_of_my_posted_entry

On the second (template_group/template_name) single entry template page it will see the URL title and use this to filter down the channel entries tag to just that one entry.

Hope that helps a bit.

Best wishes,

Comment: +1 for the thorough explanation and for including the `disable` parameter... which should be present on almost every expression engine tag IMO.